# How to pass parameter value using HttpPost and NameValuePair in android when accessing rest web service?

Tags: c#, android, wcf, rest

I made a rest web service with the service contract as shown below

```
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(Method = "POST",
            ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml,
            BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped,
            UriTemplate = "postdataa?id={id}"
            )]
string PostData(string id);
```

Implementation of the method PostData

```
public string PostData(string id)
        {
            return "You posted " + id;
        }
```

Code in Android to post data in web service

```
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpHost target = new HttpHost("192.168.1.4",4567);
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("/RestService.svc/postdataa?");

        String result=null;
        HttpEntity entity = null;

        try {
            // Add your data
            List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(1);
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("id", "1"));
            UrlEncodedFormEntity ent = new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs);
            httppost.setEntity(ent);

            // Execute HTTP Post Request
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(target, httppost);
            entity = response.getEntity();
            //get xml result in string
            result = EntityUtils.toString(entity);

} catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        }
```

**The problem is that the xml result shows and the value of the parameter is missing**:

```
<PostDataResponse xmlns="http://tempuri.org/"><PostDataResult>You posted </PostDataResult></PostDataResponse>
```

I do not know what went wrong.

Comment: Android code looks good... are you sure the server is receiving the ID?

Comment: I got the feeling that you confuse get and post in rest declaration. I don't know rest much (please provide a good link, I would appreciate) but you are describing your params as part of the uri (as in a get method) and you want to use post. I am pretty sure your service would work with id passed in the url.

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WCF/HTTP_POST_RestServiceAPI.aspx

Comment: i use post when i want to update data so i will pass the data to the service and i wanted to see the response of the service after having pass the parameter value. According to my research, the NameValuePair is used to identify the parameter name and the value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are using REST service, give this a try:

```
private static char[] GetData(String servicePath) throws Exception
{           
     InputStream stream = null;     
     String serviceURI = SERVICE_URI;//this is your URI to the service
     char[] buffer = null;
     try        
     {
        if (servicePath != "")
           serviceURI = serviceURI + servicePath; 
        DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();

        HttpGet request = new HttpGet(serviceURI);

        request.setHeader("Accept", "application/xml");
        request.setHeader("Content-type", "application/xml");

        HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(request);

        HttpEntity responseEntity = response.getEntity();    
        if (responseEntity != null)
        {
            // Read response data into buffer
            buffer = new char[(int)responseEntity.getContentLength()];
            stream = responseEntity.getContent();
            InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(stream);
            reader.read(buffer);
            stream.close();  
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Log.i("Survey Application", e.getMessage());
        throw e;
    }       
    return buffer;
}
```

Invoke this method using

```
try
{
     char[] buffer = GetData("postdataa/" + id);
     if (buffer != null)
          //Build your XML object
}
catch (Exception e)
{

}
```